What is pointwise about pointwise mutual information (PMI)?
I have just run into Positive Pointwise Mutual Information (PPMI) while learning Natural Language Processing. I don't have a good foundation in statistics. I understand why it is positive because in NLP, they don't make use of the negative PMI values. I looked at the Wikipedia pages for mutual information (MI) and pointwise mutual information (PMI) and I got a general understanding of what mutual information is but couldn't explain what made it pointwise. The mutual information page doesn't clarify beyond

MI is the expected value of the pointwise mutual information (PMI)

Now, I feel that I can't tell what PMI is doing. What points is it calculating for? I tried Google but I didn't see a source that could clarify.

Did you see this paragraph in the Wikipedia article you reference? "The concept was introduced in 1961 by Robert Fano under the name of "mutual information", but today that term is instead used for a related measure of dependence between random variables:[2] The mutual information (MI) of two discrete random variables refers to the average PMI of all possible events."

@whuber, I saw it but it doesn't make sense as to what the points are.

Each "possible event" is, abstractly, a "point," and the points are averaged.  This meaning is essentially determined by the quoted paragraph.

@whuber, could you make this an answer?

Pointwise mutual information is the log density ratio $$\log \frac{p(x, y)}{p(x)p(y)}$$
where $(x,y)$ is a ''point'' in the sample space of two jointly distributed variables $X$ and $Y$.
Intuitively, it measures how likely we are to observe $(x, y)$ together, normalized by how likely we would expect to observe them under the assumption of independence of $X$ and $Y$.
The classical Shannon mutual information is what we get when we average pointwise mutual information over all $(x,y)$.

This is simply a log likelihoodratio. Why does information theory invent a new name?

That's a bit unfair. "Information" in basically this sense was used in 1928 by Hartley, pretty much contemporaneous with Fisher's use of "likelihood" in 1920/21
